# Postman, test Graphql response

Tags: graphql, postman

I have this query:

```
query SessionQuery {
  cliente {
    id
    clienteId
    rut
    porcentajeDeCompletitudDeInformacion
    fichaCliente {
      tipoPersona
      razonSocial
    }
    representantesLegales {
      edges {
        node {
          rutRepresentante
        }
      }
    }
    documentosRequeridos {
      edges {
        node {
          iDDocumento
          cargado
          nombreDocumento
          tipoDocumentoHQB
        }
      }
    }
  }
  usuario {
    id
    usuarioId
    email
    nombre
    rut
  }
}
```

I'm testing for the first time GraphQL through Postman, like this way:
[image]

I'm having this response, I don't understand the error message:

```
{"data":{"cliente":{"id":"Q2xpZW50ZTow","clienteId":0,"rut":"XXX","porcentajeDeCompletitudDeInformacion":20,"fichaCliente":{"tipoPersona":2,"razonSocial":"ING. Y SISTEMAS BIZWARE  (Empresa Relacionada)"},"representantesLegales":{"edges":[{"node":{"rutRepresentante":null}}]},"documentosRequeridos":{"edges":[]}},"usuario":{"id":"VXN1YXJpbzoyMDI4","usuarioId":2028,"email":"XXXX@gmail.com","nombre":"XXXX","rut":"XXXX"}},"errors":[{"message":"GraphQL.ExecutionError: Cannot return null for non-null type. Field: rutRepresentante, Type: String!.\r\n   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ValidateNodeResult(ExecutionContext context, ExecutionNode node)\r\n   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteNodeAsync(ExecutionContext context, ExecutionNode node)","locations":[{"line":14,"column":11}],"path":["cliente","representantesLegales","edges","0","node","rutRepresentante"]}]}
```

I not sure what it means the error. My problem is when I call this Graphql endpoint from JavaScript I have a CORS problem in my app, but I detected with Postman that maybe the problem is this one, and the query or something is broken. Any idea please, thanks.

Comment: API returns `null` for `rutRepresentante` - but this type/property can't be null (defined in types as not nullable)

Comment: Sorry, kinda new in Graphql. I have this in the schema: `type RepresentanteLegalType {
  apellidoMaternoRepresentante: String!
  apellidoPaternoRepresentante: String!
  idRepresentante: Int!
  nombreRepresentante: String!
  rutRepresentante: String!
}` what it means that `String!`? the ! means not null? Other types has `after: String = null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xadm's comment is correct - in a standard GraphQL schema, the exclamation point means that the field is required. It's likely that the `rutRepresentante` field is NULL for the database record that your query retrieves.

Either remove the exclamation mark from `String!` in order to make the field nullable, or populate the row in the database for the `rutRepresentante` column (or key, if you're not using SQL...)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, now the Graphql response has no error in the data, anyway, always the response was 200. The CORS problem is still there, but at least the error that I was asking was fixed by this.

Comment: The CORS problem is probably happening because you have not whitelisted your client app's domain (likely `localhost` at this time in development) in your server.

There's no good way around CORS on the client....you've got to tell your server which specific domains to accept cross-origin requests from. How to go about that depends on which tech stack you're using on the back end.

Comment: Actually I had another question on SO about the CORS problem, because, in the config of the backend (NetCore on IIS) I put Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" and almost all CORS problem that I had disappeared except this one with GraphQL. I had some CORS problem with some fetch call from JavaScript, but with the rule that I said before CORS was fixed